# fourier-otf, verdana, babel-french no longer work correctly together with texlive2022

Tags: fourier

On Windows 10, LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022),
`erewthon-math` 0.53
`babel-french` 3.5n

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[french,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[math-style=french,bold-style=ISO]{fourier-otf}
%\usepackage[frenchstyle]{kpfonts-otf}        
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Test \no 11
\end{document}
```

[image]

With TeX Live 2021,
LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)
`erewthon-math` 0.46
`babel-french` 3.5m

[image]

No problem with another math font (`kpfonts-otf`).

In TeX Live 2021 `fourier-OTF` does not use `realscript` and `\RequirePackage{realscripts}` is in TeX Live 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1° As already pointed out by @egreg, your example compiles fine with an up to date TeXLive 2022 distribution (`fourier_otf` is in version 0.53).

2° Commenting out some part of a package is *always* a bad practice, please refrain to do so!

3° As far as I understand you want Erewhon Maths fonts and Verdana Text fonts. You should then load `fourier-otf` with the `no-text` option:

`\usepackage[no-text,math-style=french,bold-style=ISO]{fourier-otf}`

then `fourier-otf` will *not* load the `realscript` package meant only for Text fonts, this will solve your issue without hacking `fourier-otf`.

4° In French, abbreviations of numéro and Numéro (called `\no` and `\No` in `babel-french`) should always use a `o superscript`, the degree symbol is something else, only used as a (poor) fallback.
As the Verdana fonts have a built-in `\char"2116`,

`\DeclareRobustCommand*{\No}{texorpdfstring{\char"2116\FBmedkern}{N\textdegree\space}}`

could be a good replacement for `babel-french \No` command.
But nothing similar exists for `\no`, the faked `o superscript` looks too thin due to the lack of real superscripts in the Verdana fonts.

[image]